# What is best way to make Vim's omnicomplete context aware for ruby/rails? (i.e., intellisense)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, intellisense, omnicomplete

Vim's auto complete seems like it is just throwing the the kitchen sink at me hoping that one of the words is something I need. If I know the first couple characters of the member method, I am ok, but sometimes I can't remember if the member method is 'obj.visible' or 'obj.is_visible', in which case I get 50-1000 options to wade through.

consider the following code:

```
  class MyClass
    def some_method
    end

    def another_method
    end
  end

  def a_global_method(stuff)
    return stuff + " more stuff"
  end
```

Now if I type

```
obj = MyClass.<c-x><c-o>
```

I get 50 some options, starting with '<'.  'new' would be a great default here. Heck even if I type the n, then cx/co new isn't the first option.

It gets worse:

```
obj = MyClass.new
obj.<c-x><c-o>
```

This gives me 50 options again, and maybe they are all legit, but why not default to 'some_method' and 'another_method'?

But wait, all options aren't legit:

```
obj = MyClass.new
obj.a<c-x><c-o>
```

This only gives me 2 options, but one of them is 'a_global_method'. So obviously it is completely unaware of what a class or module are, at least with my current settings. I might as well just use  if I have to type half the member name anyway.

Speaking of which, a summary of my current settings is as follows:
rails.vim
with the following settings:

```
"omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete is set by rails.vim
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_include_object = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_include_objectspace = 1
```

I have been a loyal vim user for 12+ years, but the completion has never really worked correctly for me. I use Visual Studio at work, and use intellisense as a crutch quite often. As I don't code in rails often enough to have memorized every method, a little intellisense love would go a long way.

Is there any sort of plugin that works well? Am I just missing a setting?

Comment: I have no experience with Ruby but, as you certainly know after 12+ years, Vim is not an IDE: you *can't* really expect it to understand your code as an IDE would. For the record, testing your example on this machine doesn't even work (no completion whatsoever) even if I have Ruby support and the correct omnicompletion function. If omnicompletion is mandatory you should consider getting a proper IDE.

Comment: This may be good advice.  The downside is that I always miss editing in vim when using IDE editor, and the Vi emulation plugins they always have usually are worse than nothing. - it is too bad, as this is a feature I would pay for.

Comment: Well, on this other machine (a Mac, the first one was running Ubuntu) omnicompletion doesn't work either: it doesn't even propose anything after a `.`. The only context where it "works" is with nothing before the cursor and it gives a huge list of keywords. I mean, `<C-x><C-o>` doesn't even complete `My`. For comparison, Omnicompletion works on all my machines with the equivalent code in JS and Python but fails miserably with Ruby. You should google for "vim ruby ide", maybe both of us are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `YouCompleteMe` ?

Here [YouCompleteme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)